# app crash when click on edittext

Tags: android

when I click on Time or Date edit text neither the time picker nor the date picker appears and app crashes and in **logcat** this appears:

> Could not find method DatePickerDialog(View) in a parent or ancestor
>   Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'input2'

Thanks,in advance

here is **my activity**

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {


EditText txtDate, txtTime;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.to_do_dialog_view);

    txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input2);
    txtDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    txtTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input3);
    txtTime.setOnClickListener(this);



}


public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == txtDate) {

        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
    if (v == txtTime) {

        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

**to_do_dialog_view layout**

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:onClick="DatePickerDialog"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:hint="Time"

        android:onClick="TimePickerDialog"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove onClick from both edit texts in xml file.

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati I did this and app did not crash but the time and date picker which I want to work in my app did not appear.

Comment: what do you think `android:onClick="DatePickerDialog"` does ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:onClick="TimePickerDialog"` and `android:onClick="DatePickerDialog"` from the XML.

Set up the `onClickListener` from the Java code like you've already done.

---

**This is not necessary** if you do the above

The error states you are missing two methods.

```
public void DatePickerDialog(View v) {}
```

and

```
public void TimePickerDialog(View v) {}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work the DatepickerDialog is greyed out and tells me that the method is not used . this is the same for the other method

Comment: You do not need those methods, the bottom half of this answer only serves to tell you why you get the error in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I removed these methods but it  gives me many errors .can you post the code with its correction in the answer ?

Comment: I did post the relevant code I specifically said leave the Java code alone and remove those two lines from the XML

Comment: when I did the first part of the answer it did not crash but the timepicker and datepicker which I want to work in my app did not appear when I clicked on the edit text.

Comment: I only was addressing the error in the question, not the complete solution to solve all the problems you may encounter after that. If you would like to fix that problem, I would suggest you do `v.getId() == R.id.input2`, for example

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity3.java

```
public class MainActivity3 extends Activity{
EditText txtDate, txtTime;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.to_do_dialog_view);
    txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input2);
    txtTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input3);
}


public void datePick(View v){
  // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
}


public void timePick(View v){
 // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
}
}
```

Change EditText in layout

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="datePick" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="timePick" />
```

Comment: Why are there semi-colons in your XML?

Comment: That was a mistake. I edited it. Thanks for inform it.